# General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value 'false' for column 'status'

Tags: javascript, mysql

Estoy diseñando una vista donde se muestre un listado de comprobantes junto a un checkbox que indica si se encuentra pasado al sector de administracion o no. Quiero armarlo mediante ajax, es decir, que el usuario cambie el estado del checkbox y el mismo se ve a reflejado en la base de dato.

Codigo JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
const CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers:
    { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
});

checks.forEach((check, i) => {
    check.addEventListener('change', () => {
        const route = '{{route('comprobantes.index')}}/'+check.id;
        const check_status = check.checked;
        const check_id = check.id;

        console.log(route);

        $.ajax({
            url:route,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: {
                _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                id: check_id,
                status: check_status,
            },
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    })
})
</script>
```

Los datos logran llegar bien al controlador, el problema lo tengo a la hora de actualizar el registro.

ComprobanteController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, Comprobante $comprobante)
{
    $comprobante = Comprobante::findOrFail($request->id);
    $comprobante->update($request->all());
    
    return 'Enviado';
}
```

Modelo Comprobante.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Comprobante extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['operation', 'price', 'status','cliente_id','user_id'];
}
```

Cuando hago el cambio del check me genera el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Log Laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: BetaM ahi acabo de agregar la consola Log de laravel, puede ser que este pasando el valor 1? porque la columna de la bd es un booleano

Comment: Si, es eso. Acabo de comprobar. Esta mandando false o true en vez de 1 o 0

Comment: Correcto, eso me devuelve true o false pero la base de datos necesita 1 o 0. Hay alguna forma de que retorne 1 o 0 sin tener que realizar un if

Comment: Quedo perfecto. Ahora si anda.